# UIButton as a subview in UILabel

Tags: iphone, uibutton, uilabel

I am trying to dynamically add a `UIbutton` as a subview to `UIlable`. But I am not able to click the button. It seems that the label doesn't allow the buttonTapped event to occur.
Can somebody explain what exactly is happening here? and can anybody give me an alternative for this? thanks!

Comment: Maybe it would be a better idea to add both the `UILabel` and `UIButton` to a wrapper `UIVIew`?

Answer (score 6):

funny, I got answer on my own after 5 mins of posting this question. It seems that I had to enable my userInteraction on the labels.

i.e. -

```
lbl.userInteractionEnabled=YES;
```

Answer (score 2):

Your question (and subsequent answer) don't speak to the wisdom (or lack thereof) of doing what you're attempting. `UILabel` objects aren't generally meant to be interactive, and placing a `UIButton` as a subview to the label, just because you can do it, doesn't sound at all like it's following the Apple HIG for iPhone.

Comment: how is that an answer to the qusetion?

Comment: @Esq It is an answer!  I had the same question.  Now instead of using a UILabel, I'm changing it to a UIView which is probably a better way.